# how to reload a list WinJS

Tags: list, runtime, winjs

I want to create a list which dinamically grows after an event (take a shoot) I mean adding each picture on real time to the list, this is my method...

```
//Invoke the camera capture UI for snapping a photo
function imageCapture() {
  ...
                //Creates the array, datalist and the namespace for making this data public
                if (dataArray == null) { dataArray = new Array(); }
                dataArray[captureCount] = { title: capturedItem.name, id: "img" + captureCount, picture: photoBlobUrl };    
                var dataList            = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);
                var publicMembers       = { itemList: dataList };

                WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);

}
```

And this is the HTML page which loads the content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>eCamera</title>

    <!-- Referencias de WinJS -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Referencias de eCamera2 -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="content">
        <div id="mediumListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px;">
                <!-- Displays the "picture" field. -->
                <img src="#" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" />
                <div>
                    <!-- Displays the "title" field. -->
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h4>

                    <!-- Displays the "id" field. --> 
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: id"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="basicListView" 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource, 
                itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'), 
                itemsDraggable: true,
                itemsReorderable: true }"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load all the content in a fixed dataArray at first it works perfect, but dinamically adding elements and setting it all each time I take a picture so far doesn't work, how to make it work???

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app should not create new list each time. Use the [WinJS.Binding.List.push](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700779.aspx) method to append or splice can be used to insert. Since the list is observable, UI will autoupdate on changes (delete/add) to the list.